# How to find specific text on the screen and its location? C#

Tags: c#, ocr

I wanted to be able to **check if specific text is displayed somewhere on the screen** and, if possible, **determine its location** so that the program could display a popup above the specific text.

**I tried to use OCR** (Tesseract) to scan screenshots but it correctly sees the text about **20% of the time**, even after trying multiple image formats. Is this a common problem, is Tesseract not a great OCR, or are there any ways to improve the quality of the screenshots for the OCR to work better?

I capture and save the screenshots this way:

```
Bitmap captureBitmap = new Bitmap(1920, 1080, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
Rectangle captureRectangle = Screen.AllScreens[0].Bounds;
Graphics captureGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(captureBitmap);
captureGraphics.CopyFromScreen(captureRectangle.Left, captureRectangle.Top, 0, 0, captureRectangle.Size);
captureBitmap.Save(@"./Capture.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

The OCR (Tesseract) is implemented this way:

```
var ImagePath = "./Capture.png"; 

using (var engine = new TesseractEngine(@"./tessdata", "eng", EngineMode.Default))
{
     using (var img = Pix.LoadFromFile(ImagePath))
     {
          using (var page = engine.Process(img))
          {
                var text = page.GetText();
                if (text.Contains(selectedword))
                {
                      MessageBox.Show("This word is here");
                }
          }
     }
 }
```

**Are there any better ways to scan the screen / screenshots for specific text?**

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're going down the image/OCR route rather than using e.g. accessibility/automation facilities to interact with text in (presumably) other applications?

Comment: OCR was the first thing that came up after I've done some research. Like, I said, it works, but only in perfect conditions. Could you provide a link for more information about these accessibility facilities, how to implement them in an application to find text on the screen?